# JS Tile Map - Replacing color tiles by images

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to do a Tilemap system, so I went through a tutorial. Here's the code :

```
// Possible tile types
const TILE_TYPES = {
  0: { name: 'Sea', color: 'lightBlue'},
  1: { name: 'Land', color: 'wheat' },
  2: { name: 'House', color: 'black'}
}

// Map tile data
let mapData = <?php echo $mapData ?>

/**
Tile class
*/
class Tile {
  constructor (size, type, ctx) {
    this.size = size
    this.type = type
    this.ctx = ctx
  }

  draw (x, y) {
    // Store positions
    const xPos = x * this.size
    const yPos = y * this.size

    // Draw tile
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.type.color
    this.ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, this.size, this.size)
  }
}

/**
Map class
*/
class Map {
  constructor (selector, data, opts) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(selector)
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    this.data = data
    this.tileSize = opts.tileSize
  }
}

/**
OrthogonalMap class
*/
class OrthogonalMap extends Map {
  constructor (selector, data, opts) {
    super(selector, data, opts)
    this.draw()
  }

  draw () {
    const numCols = this.data[0].length
    const numRows = this.data.length

    // Iterate through map data and draw each tile
    for (let y = 0; y < numRows; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < numCols; x++) {
        // Get tile ID from map data
        const tileId = this.data[y][x]

        // Use tile ID to determine tile type from TILE_TYPES (i.e. Sea or Land)
        const tileType = TILE_TYPES[tileId]

        // Create tile instance and draw to our canvas
        new Tile(this.tileSize, tileType, this.ctx).draw(x, y)
      }
    }
  }
}

// Init canvas tile map on document ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Init orthogonal map
  const map = new OrthogonalMap('orthogonal-map', mapData, { tileSize: 64 })
})
```

Here's the call :

```
<?php
  $mapData = '[
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  ]';

  include "" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/maptiles.php";
?>
<canvas id="orthogonal-map" class="canvas-map" width="704" height="576"> </canvas>
```

Here's my question : How can I replace the color by an image ?

My first bet would be to replace the '`color`' attribute to the `TILE_TYPES` constant and to replace `this.ctx.fillStyle` by something like `this.ctx.drawimage`.

I'm a beginner in Javascript so I would love some explaination to your process if you have the time. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing the images on the canvas will be straightforward, however, there is a step you need to do before that requires explanation. You need to load the images and wait for them to be ready before starting executing the Javascript code. I'm going to show you the easiest way to achieve this, but there are other methods and this one has several problems. So, it is ok by now, but at some point you will learn the other ways to do it.

First, we will add at html image tags to load the images:

```
<img id="Sea" src="Sea.jpg">
<img id="Land" src="Land.jpg">
<img id="House" src="House.jpg">
<script>
...
```

The `<script>` is the start of your current code and with the `...` I mean that the code continues there, you must not write the dots into your code.

If you check the result, you will see that they appear at the top of your page, on top of the canvas. We will now tell Javascript to wait for them to load and remove them from the top of the canvas:

First lets change this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
```

by this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
```

With what you had, you were waiting for the DOM content to be loaded to start the execution. With the new code, it will wait for everything to be loaded, including the DOM content and the images.

So, now lets create some references for the images:

```
const images = {};
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    images.Sea = document.getElementById("Sea");
    images.Land = document.getElementById("Land");
    images.House = document.getElementById("House");
...
```

And now, lets remove them from the top of the canvas:

```
const images = {};
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    images.Sea = document.getElementById("Sea");
    images.Land = document.getElementById("Land");
    images.House = document.getElementById("House");
    images.Sea.parentNode.removeChild(images.Sea);
    images.Land.parentNode.removeChild(images.Land);
    images.House.parentNode.removeChild(images.House);
...
```

Now the only part missing is drawing them on the canvas. So, lets replace this:

```
// Draw tile
this.ctx.fillStyle = this.type.color
this.ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, this.size, this.size)
```

By this:

```
// Draw tile
this.ctx.drawImage(images[this.type.name], xPos, yPos);
```

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks, it's exactly what I wanted ! Now, I would like to know if there is a way to use "tileset" instead of images, and I don't know if this problem is specific to me, but does this code makes the page "laggy" ? The scrolling seems not as fluid as before, but maybe this is me. Sorry for asking this much !

Comment: As for the tileset question, read the documentation of drawImage. You can add more parameters to it, telling wich part of the image and size you want to draw, and that way you can do your tileset. But that is for you to learn and practice. About the laggy question, no idea, I haven't tried the code

Comment: L.G if the answer is what you needed please accept it so Roman gets rep for his effort.

Comment: Thanks @Anthropic, but don't worry, I definitely didn't write that much for the rep, but it seemed like a cool question for people learning... even if only L.G keeps interested in learning with, it was totally worth!

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that, more that often new users don't come back and mark answers complete when they are, so just hoping to see the question marked as answered, but all the same, everyone loves an additional 25 rep, least I could do was upvote you, I hope L.G does too :)

Comment: @Anthropic, it makes me wonder if it is a UX problem in the Stackoverflow's design. Maybe it is not letting clear enough that you are supposed to accept the answers when they are what you wanted. I'm sure it is written somewhere, but maybe it is not noticeable / flashy enough. As a new user myself too, I don't have a lot of things clear at all yet...

Comment: I'm sorry for not "accepting" your answer yesterday, I just needed to make some changes  before "validating" your code ! (As I worked on a tileset)